# How to build the table that will be suitable for big data Query process by using Mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to build the table for 30 lakhs (= 3 million) records. Currently I am working on one PHP project. 
For that I need to create a table for 30 lakhs of record. 
Based on my project that table will only be used for select statements. There is no insert,update and delete process.

I want to improve my project process speed, efficiency, etc.

For that, based on which criteria do I want to create table.
The table columns are, ***country varchar(20),state varchar(20),city varchar(20),
           created by timestamp,updated by timestamp,zipid int(11) auto_increment.***

I am working on Mysql 5.1.
According to my Mysql Knowledge there are 3 Way's to do like,

1. Create the INDEX for columns.
2. Split the table into no of table and create the view for that.
3. Create the table with partitions.

Can anyone please suggest me the best solution for my problem based on the 3 points above or anything new criteria for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

if tables would be partitioned, the query will first have to join them
thus it will take time

I would suggest using stored procedure, and the columns that are used most
in the query should be indexed

Comment: thank you for your suggestion sir and can u explain with small example.

Comment: Stored prcoedures make the query execution faster look here

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure-tutorial.aspx

for indexing use PhpMyAdmin or other DB interface to set columns as indexed

Comment: i had gone through website which you have suggested me, in that i could understand stored procedure can make it and column must be indexed but i'm having one doubt in some websites giving some information about index like if you use index for large data table the index file also grows up with the data file in disk and there may be a chance to reach the OS max file size that will decrease the performance, is it correct?

Comment: Yes it is
Specially when there are more update commands (insert, delete, update)
then select commands from the applications

u are responsible to take into the account for all the trade offs
and devise a better plan, u can use only stored procedures with
no indexing, some columns indexing (that are most used in various queries) etc, or all columns indexing